# Android Nexus 6 Bricked? TeamWin splash screen turns on and off

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking, twrp, bootloader-lock, nexus-6

I think I've bricked my Nexus 6. Every time I turn it on, the teamwin (TWRP) splash screen keeps literally flashing on and off. I would be able to flash a stock system on but I can't due to the fact that the bootloader oem is locked. I have no clue what to do as my knowledge in this is limited. Does anyone have any suggestions as how I could possibly unlock the bootloader? I have found no way to get into android and get into developer options to allow it.

Comment: Better ask in XDA: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6

Comment: Have you tried to unlock the bootloader via fastboot?

Comment: @PaulRatazzi This should work, providing the 'Enable OEM Unlock' option is enabled under Developer Options. Note that doing this will wipe all user data on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed/flashed from your SD card, try to use a new one with your stock ROM in zip form(including stock recovery). Or try a riskier method and try to use Odin3 but you need to prep all files before the screen turns on again, but make sure you have the right files(NOTE: you will have between 15-25 seconds to do this).

Comment: Only Samsung devices use Odin.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to the Boot Loader, then everything's fine.

1. Install [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)
2. `fastboot flashing unlock`
3. Flash [Factory Image](https://developers.google.com/android/images)

If you can get to TWRP Recovery, try accessing ADB Sideload

1. Install [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)
2. Flash [OTA Image](https://developers.google.com/android/ota)

---

**OEM Unlocking** :

[image]

Comment: If someone has enough reputation, please add the `https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVGGa.png` as a link! Thanks!

Comment: Done. Problem with your answer is, OP states his device is stuck in a recovery loop, and can't power on into the OS, which means no way to turn on that switch.

Comment: @AndyYan As a link! Not as an image! Yeah, boot loops are very frustrating since they involve either finding a way to not loop and get to the boot loader or replacing the motherboard.

Comment: Uh, why a link? It's an image uploaded to SE, and the content is very relevant to your answer...

Comment: @AndyYan Oh, I just thought that it wasn't relevant enough, but thanks!